# Get current width of div in percentage without calculating

Tags: jquery

I want to get the present width of a div on the screen in percentage. When I use developer tools the width is shown in percentage but when I use `$(this).width`, the width is shown in `px`. Is there any way to get width in %?

Comment: no possible without calculating

Comment: Why do you need it without calculating? If there is no function yet you would need to calculate it anyway

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Var pct = div.width * 1.0 / window.innerWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to calculate the width. The developer tools is doing all that behind the scenes, it's not actually present anywhere in the code unless you've put it in the CSS.

If it's just a percentage of the window width then you can easily do

```
($(this).width() / $(window).width()) * 100
```